# How to execute my code in RunPython Django?

Tags: django

I wrote this  code in the new file, I want to run it. How to do it? I read and follow the documentation, but did not really understand... Thanks.

```
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    product = apps.get_model("landings", "Product")
    merchant = apps.get_model("landings", "Merchant")
    partner = apps.get_model("landings", "Partner")
    operator = apps.get_model("landings", "Operator")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    partner = partner.objects.using(db_alias).filter(name="binding")
    merchant = merchant.objects.using(db_alias).filter(name="dc")
    operator = operator.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        operator(name="megafon")
    ])
    product.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        product(name="mirrorcheck", merchant=merchant,
                mnp_service_name_card="tg_247_mirrorcheck_refund",
                partner=partner,
                operator=operator,
                has_many_subs=True, category='retail',
                definition={"sms": {
                    "text": ""
    ])


def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    operator = apps.get_model("landings", "Operator")
    product = apps.get_model("landings", "Product")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    operator.objects.using(db_alias).filter(name="megafon")
    product.objects.using(db_alias).filter(name="mirrorcheck", operator=operator).delete()
    operator.delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = []
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run that migration with the command:

```
./manage.py migrate app_name 0001_migration_name
```